# How to fix the following error despite it coming from a different system?

Tags: java

The code was built and was successfully running in another system. When I ran the code in this system we were interrupted by this error:

[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: Small tip: Use simpler words. I couldn't understand the fancy language you tried to use.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: We'll need more information to be able to help. Please tell us more about these two systems, the application you're trying to run, and post some code if you can. As is we don't have much to go on and can't really help.

Comment: here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask